# Match pattern, exclude everything else

Tags: php, regex

I have some data that looks like the following.

```
\\0101 \\0102 \\0103 \\0104
\\0201 \\0202 \\0203 \\0204 \\0205 \\0206
\\0301 \\0302 \\0303 \\0304 \\0305 \\0306
```

I need to always get the digits before the last `\\` in the line.

So in the above lines, my output should be.

```
0103
0205
0305
```

I am matching these digits, but its also matching the last set.

```
(?<=\\\\)\d+(?: \\\\\d+$)
```

How can I exclude everything else except those digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, instead of using a non-capturing group `(?:` use a Positive Lookahead.

```
(?<=\\\\)\d+(?= +\\\\\d+$)
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sT6qZ2)

Comment: Thanks! I was missing something simple

Answer (score 3):

There's a many ways to do that, but to correct your regex, just add a capturing group on the target digits

```
(?<=\\\\)(\d+)(?: \\\\\d+$)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aG5fP2)

And another one (wich could be simplified more):

```
\\\\(\d+)\s+[\d\\]+$
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yX7kV4)

Comment: Thanks! I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your data are always in the same form, the lookbehind is useless. You can try this:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
\\0101 \\0102 \\0103 \\0104
\\0201 \\0202 \\0203 \\0204 \\0205 \\0206
\\0301 \\0302 \\0303 \\0304 \\0305 \\0306
LOD;

preg_match_all('~\d+(?=\D+\d+$)~m', $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing something simple.